# How to get data user API Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I use this API to take some notes from facebook page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/user/feed

It returns me object:

```
"data": [
    {
      "story": "pdated their profile picture.",
      "created_time": "2017-01-13T23:02:10+0000",
      "id": "439421442879448_707028796118710"
    },
```

How can I get photo and name of author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ask for the field:

```
/me/feed?fields=from
```

Result:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "from": {
        "name": "xxx",
        "id": "xxx"
      },
      "id": "xxx"
    },
    ...
```

...or to get pictures too:

```
/me/feed?fields=from{id,name,picture}
```

For Pages, just replace "me" with the Page ID.

Comment: I dont use `/me` I use name of another page

Comment: then use the id, it does not really matter.

Comment: Seems it was deprecated

Comment: I tried to get picture from response as: `value.from.picture.data.url`

Comment: debug the response directly, what does it include? (console.log(value))

Comment: i just tested it with a page, the api call works perfectly fine